# Lighttpd url.rewrite-once for html static fail -> Invalid controller specified

Tags: html, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I'm using lighhtpd with php. Work with Zend Framework.

I put a simple page test.html with only HTML code. When I try to see it, I get an error:

**Invalid controller specified (test.html): /test.html**

```
<!--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
and open the template in the editor.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On my conf (not htaccess)

```
url.rewrite-once = (
  ".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",
  ".*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$" => "$0",
  "" => "/index.php"
)
```

I'm lost. Try several option and not understand the problem.

Comment: ??????????????
Crazy answer. Rename all files .html to index?

Comment: You said you put a simple `test.html` page. But if you have nothing more than this page, your rewrite won't work. Add more information into your question please.

Comment: Acctually only use .php files. But now we need use .html files (test it's only a test), not only one fiel named test.html... such... file01.html, cas.html, ppe.html, contact.html, etc....

Comment: Sorry for my poor english... apreciate help and edit my question.
a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Well.

Apologize for question.

Simple.

```
url.rewrite-once = (".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",".*\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$" => "$0","" => "/index.php")
```

Changed to

```
url.rewrite-once = (".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",".*\(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$" => "$0","" => "/index.php")
```

Comment: if this is the solution to your problem please accept this as the answer by clicking the check mark button